# SQL - pulling certain records from a source table but also cross-referencing that same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a use case that I am not exactly sure what to leverage in terms of SQL syntax in order to get the results I desire.  My SQL is around a 6/10 (intermediate).  Any guidance would be appreciated!  I have my source table, below.

[image]

I then have my desired "destination table":

[image]

What I want to do is only pull out records from the source table where `ProductBusinessKey = 'CBC'`, but also cross check to see if that particular "AccountID" has a record in the source table where `ProductBusinessKey = 'HIS'`.  If a record is found, then mark the column 'HasHIS' in the destination table as `TRUE`.  Else, mark as `FALSE`.

This is where I'm stuck.  I'm just not sure if I need to do a fancy `CASE` statement, or work with ranking/partitioning.  Any ideas?

What I've tried so far is below, but it's clearly not working - it's bringing in the HIS records as well:

```
select 
    a.Account,
    b.InstrumentID,
    b.Product,
    b.OriginationDate,
    a.EmailAddress,
    b.ProductBusinessKey,
    case
        when (select count(*) from Instrument_Product_Test_2 where ProductBusinessKey in ('HIS', 'HIS2') and a.Account = Account) > 1  then 1
        else 0
    end as 'HasHIS'
from
    Member_Household_Test_2 a
inner join
    Instrument_Product_Test_2 b on a.Account = b.Account
where
    b.ProductBusinessKey in ('CBC', 'CB2') and
    a.EmailAddress = 'mmarks@fdsdfsdfs.com'
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: `CASE WHEN EXISTS() THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS HasHIS`?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I edited the question.. thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider using `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`, and a `bit` data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want to do is only pull out records from the source table where ProductBusinessKey = 'CBC', but also cross check to see if that particular "AccountID" has a record in the source table where ProductBusinessKey = 'HIS'. If a record is found, then mark the column 'HasHIS' in the destination table as TRUE. Else, mark as FALSE

You can use `EXISTS()` as

```
SELECT AccountID,
       InstrumentID,
       ProductBusinessKey,
       CASE WHEN 
       EXISTS(
       SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WHERE AccountID = T.AccountID and ProductBusinessKey = 'HIS'
       ) 
       THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END HasHIS
     --THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasHIS
FROM YourTable T
WHERE ProductBusinessKey = 'CBC'
```

You can use `0` and `1` (Bit datatype) instead of `'True'/'False'`.

Comment: Or, for the strangest of both worlds: `select Cast( 'True' as Bit ), Cast( 'False' as Bit );`.